# WSDL with a dynamic XSD

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws

Is anyone know how to  expose a WSDL with a dynamic XSD ? The choice of the XSD should depend of URL parameters given during the WSDL request. The operations of the WSDL

Prefered framework is Spring Web Service but other solutions are welcome.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Spring-ws is able to generate the WSDL on the fly, based on your XSD files. I'm not sure if this is what you want since you're changing the webservice definition. In my opinion you should only have one definition.

Perhaps it's an option to provide multiple entry points, based on different XSD's. Since Spring-WS can take care of generating the WSDL that might be an option for you. It would at least provide you with only one WSDL.

Another option is of course to create a REST service where you're free to implement this any way you'd like.